# Issue JWT tokens from Spring OAuth2 Authorization Server when authenticating with Google

Tags: jwt, google-oauth, spring-oauth2

I want to create an authorization server using Spring Oauth which is able to issue it's own JWT tokens. The authorization server must delegate the authentication to Google. I have been following this tutorial which does almost everything I want: https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/

I was able to add Google as an authentication provider, but I'm struggling with the JWT part.

Here's my authorization server configuration:

```
@SpringBootApplication 
@EnableOAuth2Client
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
public class MsAuthorizationGmailApplication extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    OAuth2ClientContext oauth2ClientContext;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/login**", "/webjars/**").permitAll().anyRequest()
            .authenticated().and().exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login/gmail")).and().logout()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll().and().csrf()
            .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()).and()
            .addFilterBefore(ssoFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("gmail")
    public ClientResources gmail() {
        return new ClientResources();
    }

    private Filter ssoFilter() {
        CompositeFilter filter = new CompositeFilter();
        List<Filter> filters = new ArrayList<>();
        filters.add(ssoFilter(gmail(), "/login/gmail"));
        filter.setFilters(filters);
        return filter;
    }

    private Filter ssoFilter(ClientResources client, String path) {
        OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter filter = new     OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter(
            path);
        OAuth2RestTemplate template = new OAuth2RestTemplate(client.getClient(), oauth2ClientContext);
        filter.setRestTemplate(template);
        filter.setTokenServices(JwtConfig.tokenServices());
        return filter;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MsAuthorizationGmailApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

In the JWT config I'm not trying to do anything fancy, just trying to make it pass for now:

```
public final class JwtConfig {

    private static final String KEY = "123";

    private JwtConfig() {
    }

    private static JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        converter.setSigningKey(KEY);
        return converter;
    }

    private static TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
    }

    public static DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
        DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
        defaultTokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
        return defaultTokenServices;
    }
}
```

I get the following exception:

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Could not obtain user details from token
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.filter.OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:122) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.12.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:112) [spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:73) [spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
....
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_121]
Caused by: org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.exceptions.InvalidTokenException: Cannot convert access token to JSON
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JwtAccessTokenConverter.decode(JwtAccessTokenConverter.java:287) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.12.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JwtTokenStore.convertAccessToken(JwtTokenStore.java:88) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.12.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JwtTokenStore.readAccessToken(JwtTokenStore.java:80) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.12.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices.loadAuthentication(DefaultTokenServices.java:229) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.12.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.filter.OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:112) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.12.RELEASE.jar:na]
... 62 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: JWT must have 3 tokens
at org.springframework.security.jwt.JwtHelper.decode(JwtHelper.java:49) ~[spring-security-jwt-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.security.jwt.JwtHelper.decodeAndVerify(JwtHelper.java:74) ~[spring-security-jwt-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JwtAccessTokenConverter.decode(JwtAccessTokenConverter.java:277) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.12.RELEASE.jar:na]
... 66 common frames omitted
```

How I understand this: It looks like that when Google issues an access token, the authorization server (being a client of Google OAuth) tries to decode the access token as a JWT, and throws an exception because Google's token is not a valid JWT (it's just an access token).

I would like to create a JWT containing the access token (which will be used to access Google APIs) and some additional information about the user. I would also like to be able to refresh the JWT token when the access token expires. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure about GMail but for your own Authorization server, you can add one token enhancer `JwtAccessTokenConverter` which will convert you token into JWT.

For sample, pls refer [oauth2-spring-boot-mongo-jwt-sample](https://github.com/sharmaritesh/oauth2-spring-boot-mongo)

Generally, normal token payload is of below type

```
{
    "access_token": "bc9c021f-b5ae-43af-9746-737b533f9bc5",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "refresh_token": "fee7a2a1-eff9-4757-8dd3-5392ee225bea",
    "expires_in": 43199,
    "scope": "read-foo" }
```

whereas, JWT looks something like this

```
{
    "access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhdWQiOlsiZm9vIl0sInVzZXJfbmFtZSI6InVzZXIiLCJzY29wZSI6WyJyZWFkLWZvbyJdLCJleHAiOjE1MTQ3ODMwNTIsImF1dGhvcml0aWVzIjpbIlJPTEVfVVNFUiJdLCJqdGkiOiJlMjM4MDg1YS0xZjFjLTQ5ZWQtODNiMC1iN2Q1MjI5OWUwZjYiLCJjbGllbnRfaWQiOiJ3ZWItY2xpZW50In0.-OSw1Vr4o1dnAQL3n7QFGG6UOXr4itc0Kp8dugyT4zU",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "refresh_token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhdWQiOlsiZm9vIl0sInVzZXJfbmFtZSI6InVzZXIiLCJzY29wZSI6WyJyZWFkLWZvbyJdLCJhdGkiOiJlMjM4MDg1YS0xZjFjLTQ5ZWQtODNiMC1iN2Q1MjI5OWUwZjYiLCJleHAiOjE1MTczMzE4NTIsImF1dGhvcml0aWVzIjpbIlJPTEVfVVNFUiJdLCJqdGkiOiIzYTA2OTZmMy1mYzg1LTQ2YTEtYjVlMC01NmQ2OGVmYTJhMmUiLCJjbGllbnRfaWQiOiJ3ZWItY2xpZW50In0.jSBriPfM-rSgHHLyifIuBHwrwCkyb5I2u2AKa8kQUUU",
    "expires_in": 43199,
    "scope": "read-foo",
    "jti": "e238085a-1f1c-49ed-83b0-b7d52299e0f6"
}
```